# WPF upgrade from 2010 to 2013 Validation Issues

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, binding, visual-studio-2013

I want to upgrade a WPF project that was created in Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013 and I am having issues with the way validation has changed.

In VS 2010, I could create a Validation.Error tag that pointed to an event handler in my C# code.  Then I could trap the action and if it was added, I could show a message box with an error string that was built during validation.

I also used the event handler to simulate key strokes and set the focus to any control and do anything else that I needed done.

However in VS 2013, the Validation tag now wants an ErrorTemplate, and I have only found examples where they are used on a single control, not the entire user control, and they don't provide a way to use an event handler like I am doing in VS 2010.  Can someone please provide an example of how to do this in VS 2013 at the user control level?

The following is an example of a code snippet I am using in VS 2010 to add clarity to my question:

Here is the xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PDMonitorClient.LabResultsUserControls.uc24HourBatchOnly"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:igWPF="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml/wpf"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="320"
             d:DesignWidth="797"
             DataContext="{Binding}"
             Validation.Error="TwentyFourHourBatchOnlyCollectionSample_Error"
             x:Name="TwentyFourHourBatchOnlyCollectionSample"
             Unloaded="TwentyFourHourBatchOnlyCollectionSample_Unloaded"
             IsVisibleChanged="TwentyFourHourBatchOnlyCollectionSample_IsVisibleChanged"
             Loaded="TwentyFourHourBatchOnlyCollectionSample_Loaded">
```

Here is my C# snippet:

```
/// <summary>
        /// This event is fired by WPF binding
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void TwentyFourHourBatchOnlyCollectionSample_Error( object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e )
        {
            try
            {
                if( this.Visibility == Visibility.Visible )
                {
                    if( e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added )
                    {
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)( () =>
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show( e.Error.ErrorContent.ToString(), "Validation Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Hand );

                            //
                            // The following code will insure that the focus is at the control with the error whether the user taps enter and causes
                            // the message box to popup up, or enters in a value and then clicks on another control.  End result, no matter what,
                            // the user is back in the control with the invalid value.
                            //
                            InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke( VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT, VirtualKeyCode.TAB );
                            InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress( VirtualKeyCode.TAB );
                            string OriginalSourceTypeName = e.OriginalSource.GetType().Name;
                            if( OriginalSourceTypeName == "XamMaskedEditor" )
                            {
                                ( (XamMaskedEditor)( e.OriginalSource ) ).Focus();
                            }
                        } ) );

                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch( Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think you might mean .Net 4.0 vs 4.5 changes, not VS

Comment: Thank you for putting a finer point on the question.  Do you have any thoughts about Validation.Error and Validation.ErrorTemplate so I can achieve the results I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer.  Seems like intellisense was giving precedence to Validation.ErrorTemplate, when I forced the issue and typed Validation.Error and then deleted the Template part, I got what I needed and that was an event that would be fired if there was a error.

Please see the following Microsoft article: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
This event is very helpful to me and I am really glad to hear that I am not loosing access to it.